# Android: My Own App Takes Ages To "Compute" under "Manage applications" and is Generally Slow

Tags: android, performance

I have a fledgling app under development, which I am installing to my Android phone via Eclipse debugging.

Now, my app is only 200KB in size at the moment, but it runs very slowly.  I have a button in my first activity that drops 4 SQLite tables, with a combined total of no more than 25 records, and then recreates the tables and data straight away.  To my mind, this should be a pretty damn fast operation, but it takes a good 4 or 5 seconds.

There isn't anything else going on at that moment in time, netiher in the app, or on my phone. I just can't understand how it can be so sluggish.  I've even made the operation above an AsyncTask, and it's made no difference.

Also, when I go into my phone's Settings -> Manage applications, the list of all my installed apps shows that they're all "computing...".  Every single other app finishes this a good 3 or 4 seconds before my tiny one stops "computing..." and displays the app size info, etc.

Could all this just be symptomatic of an app not having been installed via the Marketplace?  Is it something to do with the debuggable setting in my Manifest?

I'm not ready to play around with signing and release yet, not by a long shot, so I can't test to see if that's the reason.  Or can I?

Comment: Is this on a device (which one) or the emulator?

Comment: Runs terribly on the two devices I've tried (Samsug Galaxy S and HTC Desire). I haven't actually tried the emulator just yet, as I've always had a device to hand. Next time I get to my development machine I'll try it on there and report back. Regardless, there's a slowness issue on physical devices, which I need to nip in the bud before I proceed with development. Unless it *is* something to do with being a debug/third-party app?

Comment: I would suggest posting up some code so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a button in my first activity that drops 4 SQLite tables, with a combined total of no more than 25 records, and then recreates the tables and data straight away. To my mind, this should be a pretty damn fast operation, but it takes a good 4 or 5 seconds.

1. Writing to flash is not as consistent, speed-wise, as is writing to magnetic media. Brad Fitzpatrick, in the 2010 Google I|O conference, cited some tests he ran where writing a single byte to flash, while normally fast, could take as long as 200ms.
2. If you are not using transactions, things will be slower, because there is a flash write and sync on every database operation.

Beyond that, it is difficult to provide you with advice, particularly with no code to examine.

> I'm not ready to play around with signing and release yet, not by a long shot, so I can't test to see if that's the reason. Or can I?

Well, you can certainly sign it. For release testing, you can put the app on a Web server somewhere that is set up with the proper MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`), or send it to your device via Dropbox, or something.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps I'll post up the code when I get home, but, really, it's just some drops, creates and inserts. There's very little scope for me to have screwed it up...I hope! :) I just think there has to be something else intrinsically "wrong" with my app (of my own doing), because of how long it takes Android to compute its size in the app list, as well as the overall speed it runs at.

Comment: @JimBadger: Yeah, the computing-size problem seems odd, but I haven't exactly spent tons of time staring at that screen and trying to compare calculation speeds. That's why I didn't comment on it earlier.

Comment: I'll try signing non-debug mode and releasing in the manner you suggested. I'll also read up on transactions to see if that'll speed up my 20-odd insert statements. If it makes a 4 second difference though, I'd be amazed.

Comment: Just popped back to accept this answer.  I read up on transactions, implemented a few simple lines of code, as per the example at the URL below, and the difference was fantastic.  Thanks

http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html

Comment: @JimBadger: Yeah, in non-mobile environments, transactions are for business logic and data integrity. In mobile, they can offer a significant performance improvement as well. BTW, did this help with calculating your app's size in the Settings app? I'd be surprised if it did, but, then again, I have no idea what might have been causing that problem in the first place...

Comment: No, but on rechecking that seems to be more of an issue on the Galaxy S rather than the Desire...